# How to read multiple addresses' value in loop C#

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of addresses that I have dumped in a file and would like to read the value of each address and write it to another file. I have tried this

```
foreach (string s in lines)
{
    int address = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);
    IntPtr _address = new IntPtr(address);
    ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, _address, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"dump.dump", true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer) + s);
    }
}
```

And I have used the ReadProcessMemory is declared as

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

This gives me a rather odd result in the console and in the file so I guess the conversion from the `string[] lines` which contain the addresses read from a text file (each in a new line) in the format of

```
10418CF3
1063DEAD
1063DECA
1063DEED
1063DF4B
1063E271
//etc

Console.WriteLine("Enter filename:");
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Console.ReadLine());
```

Without the leading `0x` to indicate it's in hex. Should I just loop through every line and add the `0x` in front of the line or is there and easier way to do it from the state it is in?

Comment: can you please post a sample of you input (the lines variables)

Comment: @Luiso ah sorry forgot to add that I read the array from a text file and the array `string[] s` should be `string[] lines`

Comment: so you are trying to convert whatever `string` you are supplied with into an `int` something like `int.Parse(line)`

Comment: @Luiso yes, I know for sure each line in the text file contains a hex address that I wish to read, so normally I would just add a `0x` to the number and it would work, but I now have 10 000 addresses to read and I need to convert them to the correct pointer, e.g. 1063E271 should become 0x1063E271 as a normal int.

Comment: then your question should be how to parse to hex numbers. Worst case scenario you could could say something as `int.Parse("0x" + line)`, though there would be some performance penalty.

Comment: "rather odd result" doesn't tell us what the problem is. `Convert.ToInt32(s, 16)` is the right way to do it. What is your odd results, how do you know they're odd?

Comment: `int.Parse("0x" + line)` won't work, `int.Parse` doesn't know how to handle hexadecimal, `Convert.ToInt32(s, 16)` is the correct way to do it and will handle the example strings just fine.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen here is what the file looks like after finished reading the memory https://i.gyazo.com/3b64e6dad118ef3420bc01e58c571675.png and it goes on for ages.

Comment: And what is the problem with that?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen well that's odd, I tried making an example with 3 random addresses and they give the exact same result. I think I have found the problem and it has nothing to do with the question (something is wrong with the addresses). Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the 0x where needed at the point where you are going to use the value e.g.

```
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            DoSomethingWithValue(line.Contains("0x") ? line : "0x" + line);
        }
```